# Por que é errado falar "mais grande" e "mais pequeno"?

Tags: advérbios

Por que não posso usar o advérbio de intensidade "mais" para os adjetivos "grande" e "pequeno"?

Comment: Não sei ainda qual é o escopo desse site, mas eu acho que no português de Portugal esse uso é o mais correto. Certa vez por lá eu disse "menor" e me corrigiram para que usasse "mais pequeno". :)

Comment: @LuizVieira não tá confundindo com espanhol não? :) Sei que em espanhol se fala "más grande" e "más pequeño", mas não sabia disso em pt_pt.

Comment: @Math Não. Eu estava em Portugal mesmo (em Barcelos) quando isso aconteceu. :)

Comment: "Mais pequeno" pode-se dizer em pt_pt, mas não é preferível a "menor" — é indiferente qual dos dois se usa. "Mais grande" _nunca_ se usa.

Comment: "Mais grande" pode se usado, mas somente num contexto bem específico, quando a "grandeza" é contrastada com outra qualidade - "mais grande do que maduro", "mais grande do que forte", "mais grande do que inteligente".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Não consigo decidir se **mais grande** é errado ou se é simplesmente mau estilo. Afinal, não é o mesmo que dizer *nós estou, amanhã estive*, ou *preciso urgente de ajuda*, onde existem claramente erros. *Mais grande* até faz sentido, mas os falantes do português ao longo dos séculos optaram pela forma sintética *maior*. Esta é a única razão apresentada para *maior* em vez de *mais grande* [neste artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/mais-grande/1054). De acordo com o mesmo artigo, *mais grande* pode no entanto ocorrer com significados que não *maior:*

> Este edifício é mais grande que imponente. (Mais facilmente o qualificamos de *grande* que de *imponente*; não é o mesmo que *é maior que imponente*, que nem sequer faz sentido.)
>
> "Que coisa mais grande!" exclamou ela. (Mesmo que "que coisa tão grande!")

Já **mais pequeno** é aceite. O gramático brasileiro [Evanildo Bechara, citado aqui no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-construcao-mais-grande-do-que/29908) diz

> Não se diz mais bom nem mais grande em vez de melhor e maior; mas podem ocorrer mais pequeno, o mais pequeno, mais mau, por menor, o menor, pior.

E o [Novo Dicinário Aurélio, citado neste outro artigo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-comparativo-de-superioridade-de-pequeno-mais-pequeno-ou-menor/16506), afirma que *mais pequeno* é "corretíssimo."

Agora não sei se isto se refere só a Portugal? O último artigo dia que é "quanto ao Brasil," mas todos os brasileiros me dizem que *mais pequeno* não se diz no Brasil. Já em Portugal, *mais pequeno* é até a forma normalmente usada para comparar tamanhos habitualmente avaliados visualmente:

> O meu carro/cão/gato é mais pequeno que o teu. Esta casa é mais pequena que aquela.

Já para comparar grandezas expressas habitualmente por números, *menor* já é bastante usado, talvez até preferido a *mais pequeno*:

> "X < Y" lê-se xis é menor que ípsilon. (Nunca *mais pequeno*.)
> A densidade populacional é no Brasil menor que em Portugal.
> A distância entre Lisboa e Porto é menor que a entre o Rio e São Paulo.

Comment: Seria aceitável a forma composta quando numa série de adjetivos? Ex: *este cão é mais inteligente e grande do que esse*? Ou haveria-de dizer *é mais inteligente e (é também) maior*?

Comment: @guifa "mais inteligente e maior" é preferível, mas admito que seja possível. O CETEMPúblico tem uma entrada relevante para `"mais" [pos="ADJ"] "e" "grande"`, mas é uma citação de uma pessoa escolhida ao acaso que foi ver um presépio.

Comment: @guifa "mais inteligente e maior" também me soa mais natural e melhor.

Comment: Muito interessante a sua resposta, nunca tinha pensado no «mais grande» vs «mais pequeno». A irregularidade da nossa língua chega a ser fascinante. (não sei como não tinha visto ainda esta resposta)

Comment: @JorgeB., és um distraído. Encontrei algures que nalguns falares do Nordeste brasileiro se diz "mais grande, mais mau" e coisas assim.

Comment: @Jacinto Não seja por isso: nalguns falares do noroeste português diz-se "mais maior" e coisas assim... ; )

Comment: @ANeves mas não deixa de ser considerado errado por cá...

Comment: @ANeves, "mais maior que melhor" está correto.

Answer (score 4):

Por que estes adjetivos são irregulares, em termos de intensidade, e têm uma forma própria - "maior" e "menor".

Comment: Eles têm a própria forma por que são irregulares ou são irregulares por que tem a própria forma?

Comment: .... Não há grande diferença, mas acho que a primeira.

Answer (score 2):

Sou brasileiro. Esta forma está correta, pelo menos eu havia aprendido na escola assim.

Que eu saiba, usamos a forma analítica de superioridade quando há composição de 2 adjetivos:
Ela é mais **grande** que **bonita** (exemplo bobo)
Adjetivos: grande e bonita

A forma sintética (maior, menor, pior), é usada na composição de 2 substantivos:
Este **quarto** é maior que a **sala** de casa.
Substantivos: quarto e sala

Answer (score 1):

Em Portugal, uma pessoa me disse que mais grande, mais pequeno, mais bom e mais ruim (ou mau) são aceitos, além de maior, menor, melhor e pior. Ou seja, as duas formas são corretas no Português de Portugal. Já o Português do Brasil aceita apenas maior, menor, melhor e pior.

Comment: Talvez essa pessoa estivesse a brincar contigo: *mais grande, mais bom* e *mais mau* **não** são aceites em Portugal e raramente se ouvem; *ruim*, quase não usamos. Diz-se *ruim como as cobras* e pouco mais.

Comment: "uma pessoa me disse" não é um bom embasamento para um resposta, talvez fosse legal você complementá-la com fontes confiáveis

Answer (score 0):

Menor, ou maior são termos comparativos de tamanho. Podemos dizer maior ou menor referindo-nos a algo citado anteriormente ou a ser citado posteriormente, sempre precedido por "que": ...maior que, ou, menor que. Neste caso, mais grande, ou mais pequeno são sinônimos de maior e menor... queiram ou não os eruditos.

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente eu não acho que esteja mesmo errado. Pra mim é o mesmo caso de pego, pegado, pago, pagado. Os dois estão certos! Só que alguém te corrige quando você fala assim e os dois estão certos. Você esta certo em dizer uma pessoa te falou e não esta errado. Já vi alguns vídeos de canas de Portugal e eles realmente falam mais grandes e mais pequenos, mais ruins e mais bons. Se veio de la e está certo, porque aqui estaria errado?

Answer (score 0):

Quando nos referimos a membros pares do corpo humano ex: mãos, pernas....Podemos usar mais grade. Ex: Minha mão esquedar é mais grande que a direita.Etc.