# Unlike ptBR, ptPT accepts the phrase "mais pequeno do que" as current usage. What about "mais grande que"? Is it acceptable in Portugal?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, grau-comparativo

"mais pequeno que" sounds awkward to a Brazilian ear.  We say "menor que" and "o menor" when using the comparative and superlative degrees respectively. I know "mas grande que" and "mas pequeño que" are both current usage in Spanish. Do people ever say "mais grande que" (comparative degree) in Portugal?

Comment: For the record, Spanish also uses [*mayor* and *menor* as irregular comparatives](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlativo) — but you still hear *más grande* and *más pequeño*.

Comment: @tchrist  Don't the Spanish use "mayor" and "menor" only as superlatives?

Comment: No, they can be comparative. For superlatives, if you have a determinate article, it is a superlative, and if you don’t it isn’t: *El mayor océano del mundo es el Pacífico* is superlative. See [this Brazilian site in Portuguese](http://www.tradutoradeespanhol.com.br/2013/04/mayor-mas-grande-menor-mas-pequeno.html) for an explanation of the possible alternatives in which they point out how this is different from Portuguese.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the explanation and the link.  I can see it now.

Comment: [Related](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/17/por-que-%C3%A9-errado-falar-mais-grande-e-mais-pequeno)

Comment: @JNat  Yes, related, but not exactly the same.  There is one comment about what I'm asking here, and the only answer sounds more like a brief piece of information.

Comment: @Centaurus Hence why I said "related", and not "possible duplicate." ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

According to my native experience, `mais grande que` is not acceptable in Portugal.

## Exception

When one compares two objects, one says `este carro é _maior_ que o outro`.

But when one compares two properties of the same object, one would instead say `o carro é mais grande que espaçoso`.

---

Fonte: [A construção «mais grande do que»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-construcao-mais-grande-do-que/29908) , in *CiberDúvidas da Língua Portuguesa*, consultado a 31-08-2015.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, people do use *mais grande que*, although it's generally accepted as a wrong form.